# Android bitmap manipulation problems - setPixels() issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bitmap

I have tried to keep the code to a bare minimum. I've been trying to create a steganography app but the `setPixels()` function is giving me too much trouble.

Just to highlight the essence of my app and issues, I've included below a skeleton code with minimum functionality.

I'm first selecting an image from gallery (google photos app in the emulator) and encoding it -

```
Button btn;
    private static int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    private static Uri imageUri;
    private static Bitmap bmp;
    private static int random;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                bmp=bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);
                encode();
                //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bmp,"encodedImage",null);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, readClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encode() {
        random = new Random().nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("random " + random);
        int height = bmp.getHeight();
        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int pixels[] = new int[height * width];
        bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        System.out.println("before setting pixel: "+pixels[random]);
        pixels[random]= Color.CYAN;
        bmp.setPixels(pixels,0,width,0,0,width,height);
        System.out.println("immediately after setting pixel: "+pixels[random]);
    }

    public static int sendRandom()
    {
        return random;
    }
```

Below is my read class activity -

```
private static int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    private static Uri imageUri;
    private static Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_class);
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);
                int height = bmp.getHeight();
                int width = bmp.getWidth();
                int pixels[] = new int[height * width];
                bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                if(pixels[MainActivity.sendRandom()]== Color.CYAN)
                {
                    System.out.println("succeeded: "+pixels[MainActivity.sendRandom()]);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            //imgView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
```

Below is my output from logcat -

```
2020-05-15 19:36:08.528 6603-6603/com.example.testingpurpose1_steg I/System.out: random 2
2020-05-15 19:36:08.530 6603-6603/com.example.testingpurpose1_steg I/System.out: before setting pixel: -11123664
2020-05-15 19:36:08.531 6603-6603/com.example.testingpurpose1_steg I/System.out: immediately after setting pixel: -16711681
2020-05-15 19:36:18.122 6603-6603/com.example.testingpurpose1_steg I/System.out: Failed
```

1. `setPixels()` doesn't seem to save the image. Is that correct?
2. Assuming it doesn't save the image, I included the commented line to save to gallery. However, even after giving WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, it just doesn't work.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. What can I try next?